# How to retrieve a forgotten Yahoo! Mail password

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

I have forgotten my Yahoo! Mail account password. What is the procedure to retrieve my password?

Note that I'm not asking where the link is. I want to learn about the procedure (i.e. if they ask me about my birthday, the secret question which I defined years ago, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following Yahoo!'s [I can't access my account](https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot) link on the main page, Yahoo! takes you to Forgot Password page along with a Captcha, asking for your **alternate e-mail address**. If you provide it, Yahoo! sends your password to that e-mail address. If you skip alternate e-mail verification, Yahoo! asks **2 secret questions** that you've already provided for your account. If you give the correct answers, you are allowed to reset the password of your account.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo's Forgot Password Link: https://edit.yahoo.com/forgotroot - At which point you be asked to fill in your Yahoo account name along with a Captcha, then Yahoo will email a link to an account listed in Yahoo account as the backup email account. Click the link and reset your password.

Hotmail's Forgot Password Link: https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx